# Entity Foreign Key not in model

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am using EF5 and .NET 4.6  I have a table Invoice that has a FK to Address called Address_no.  When I add the table to the entity model, the table adds fine but the FK is not present as a field, instead there is a navigation property to Address.  So when I do a data binding to Address_no, it fails because Address_no is not in the model.  How do I get around this?

It fails at Databinding.Add

```
If isDate Then
    control.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding(controlProperty, bs, field, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
Else
    If format = "" Then
        control.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding(controlProperty, bs, field, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))
    Else
        control.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding(controlProperty, bs, field, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing, format))
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the EF Designer, be sure to select the "Add Foreign Key Properties to the 'xxx' Entity" option.

[image]

See [Relationships - EF Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I never found a good answer to this.  Sometimes it just fails - I think the model had some table relations that were not working. The only solution was to create a new model.